# How to get shape of a road link

Tags: here-api

I want to get the shape of a road link (form one node to another node, i.e. between 2 junctions) but I cannot find how to do it.

If I try with

[https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?app_id=&app_code=&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1&level=9&tilex=537&tiley=399](https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?app_id=%3Cnyapp_id%3E&app_code=%3Cmycode%3E&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1&level=9&tilex=537&tiley=399)

there is no shape.

This is to store the shape in my geoserver to later reuse the map. I am not sure this is doable according to the commercial license... So any commercial explanation is also welcome.

Is there a price for this? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ADAS attribute layer would be more useful for your use case:

https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1&level=9&tilex=537&tiley=399

Example out of the response: 
[...]

```
"LINK_ID": "52493206",
    "HPX": "89681500,-1400,-8000",
    "HPY": "502884700,1900,11200",
    "HPZ": "18242,22,138",
    "SLOPES": "547,-2,92",
    "HEADINGS": "334899",
    "CURVATURES": "-116",
    "VERTICAL_FLAGS": "0",
    "REFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "9588455:-110:-25252",
    "NREFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "1143217772:-111:335789",
    "BUA_ROAD": "4",
    "BUA_ROAD_VERIFIED": "Y"
  }, {
    "LINK_ID": "52493207",
    "HPX": "89658700,-8700",
    "HPY": "502913000,13500",
    "HPZ": "18592,167",
    "SLOPES": "525,70",
    "HEADINGS": "",
    "CURVATURES": "",
    "VERTICAL_FLAGS": "",
    "REFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "497590520:-88:-22269",
    "NREFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS": "869077244:-83:338527",
    "BUA_ROAD": "4",
    "BUA_ROAD_VERIFIED": "Y"
  },
```

[...]

Here you can see all available layer and the data they contain:

https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.json?&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

Update: Regarding storing of the data please go through the Terms and Conditions on Here Website. https://legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/here-wego-here-application-and-here-maps-service-terms

> You undertake that you will safeguard, protect, and keep your HERE
>   account confidential and shall not disclose it to any person, or store
>   the information in any manner, except as required by law.